# Authentication error while uploading file or sending email aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

By mistakenly I **deleted all the IAM users** from aws. And Now when I tried to  upload the file into aws via node.js code, I am getting the error:

> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

and when I trying to send the email from node.js code with ses credentials, I am getting the error:

> Invalid login: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid.

However, I created new access key and secret key pair to solve this problem, But still same issue. Can anyone please help with the same?

Comment: Are you using the new key and secret in the code? The keys have appropriate permissions to send email and upload files?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Yes I am using the new access key and secret key credentials in my code. But still the same error.

Comment: I don't know, Is the have appropriate permissions to send email and upload files. How can I give the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"535 Authentication Credentials Invalid" occurs when you use SMTP. It looks like you have created a IAM user from IAM console which access key and secret key won't work with SES with SMTP. You need to go to SES console and create a SMTP credentials from there (In SMTP settings), it basically also create an IAM user but the secret key is different for when accessing with SMTP.
Doing this, it'll automatically give the appropriate permissions, you don't need to define the policy and stuff.

Comment: Thanks JamesDean and what about the files uploading error? Can you please help with that also.

Comment: "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." This also says the same thing, the Access key you're using either you have mistyped or doesn't exist. You can actually go to IAM console --> users and search based on the access key.

Comment: But I don't have any user in IAM as I deleted all users mistakenly

Comment: okay , the message shows correct information then, you can create a new one and use that access key to upload.